# why onClick isn't working on my react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

onclick isn't working on my react component, here is my code:

```
const listItems = xox.map((nums) =>
    <Square key={nums.index} cont={nums.content} onclick={function (){
        alert();
    }}/>
);
```

also i tried this but alert working on the when render the page:

```
    <Square key={nums.index} cont={nums.content} onclick={alert()}/>
```

my app function:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <header>
          <img src={logo} alt="React logo"/>
            <h1>XOX</h1>
        </header>
        <div className="playground">
            {listItems}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Square.js

```
import React from "react";
export class Square extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <div className="square" onClick={this.props.onclick}>
            {this.props.cont}
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure your Square component accepts and then uses an `onclick` prop. For example, something like:

```
const Square = ({ cont, onclick }) => (
  <div onClick={onclick}>{cont}</div>
);
```

Otherwise the prop will be ignored, since it's not used inside the component.

> also i tried this but alert working on the when render the page:

Yes, you need to pass a *function* as a prop, not *invoke* the function then pass the result as a prop. This:

```
return <Square key={nums.index} cont={nums.content} onclick={alert()}/>
```

is equivalent to doing

```
const result = alert();
return <Square key={nums.index} cont={nums.content} onclick={result}/>;
```

So you instead need

```
onclick={() => alert()}
```

(or with the `function` keyword as you're already doing, though it's less terse)

If possible, I'd also suggest using the standard capitalization for React click handlers, which is `onClick`, not `onclick` - there's less chance of confusing people that way.

Comment: that worked thanks! :)

Answer (score -2):

try using arrow functions:

```
<Square key={nums.index} cont={nums.content} onClick={() => alert('hello world')}/>
```

Comment: i tried this but isn't worked :(

Comment: its onClick. Check spelling

Comment: isn't worked, i write onclick to h1 and it's worked. maybe error about square.

Comment: If Square is a custom component, you'll have to handle it with props.